# Tabu search algorithm for timetabling in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, tabu-search

I'm making this automated timetabling system for middle school using CodeIgniter and Tabu search algorithm with constraints

But i dont know how to start, i've already get the data of subjects, teachers, lesson hurs, and class. After i get those data i dont know what i should do next, also the constraints.

Does anybody have any idea or any suggestion about what i should do?
Or what link with tutorial about tabu search algorithm in php or codeigniter code that i can visit?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you try Google ? It's a new website, some people say it is a good one for searching.

Comment: @VincentDecaux i've tried to search it on google but i still dont understand